# Reshape pandas df: rows of values to boolean matrix

Tags: python, pandas

There is a pandas dataframe:

```
id, key
1, A
1, B
1, B
1, C
2, C
```

And I want it to look like this (where 1/0 is True/False appearance in data):

```
id, A, B, C
1, 1, 1, 1
2, 0, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['id', 'key']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
key  A  B  C
id          
1    1  1  1
2    0  0  1
```

Or [`get_dumes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and `max` by `index` - if multiple `1` always return `1`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id')['key']).max(level=0)
print (df)
    A  B  C
id         
1   1  1  1
2   0  0  1
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this,

```
temp=pd.get_dummies(df['key']).replace(0,np.NaN)
df=pd.concat([df,temp],axis=1)
df= df.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda x:x.fillna(method='bfill'))
print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id']).fillna(0)
```

Output

```
   id key    A    B    C
0   1   A  1.0  1.0  1.0
4   2   C  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: why down vote? please explain so that i won't repeat